# Upper bound for the modulus of bounded holomorphic function in the unit disk with $f(a)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic on the unit disk and $|f(z)|≤ M$ for $|z|<1$. Assume that $f(a)=0$ for some $|a|<1$. Prove that $|f(z)|≤(M|z-a|)/(|1-a ̅z|)$ for $|z|<1$.

#### Progress

I want to apply maximum modulus principle but I could not see how. Please help me out providing me some idea.

Comment: I want to apply maximum modulo principle but I could not see how to apply. Please help me out providing me some idea.

Comment: Do you know the Schwarz Lemma?

Comment: yes, in this problem how can I apply? could you explain a little more.

Comment: Divide $f$ by the right hand side of the inequality that you wish to prove. Call the result $g$. Prove that it's holomorphic, and bounded by $1$ near the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a so-so suggestion in a comment; here's a better approach.

1. Recall (or prove) that the map $w=\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar az }$ is a bijection of the unit disk onto itself. With a little algebra, its inverse is seen to be $z =\dfrac{w+a}{1+\bar aw}$.
2. Since $M|w|$ appears in the inequality you want, let's consider the composition $g(w) = f(\frac{w+a}{1+\bar aw})$. Then the desired inequality becomes $g(w)\le M|w|$.
3. The function $\frac{1}{M}g$ satisfies the assumptions of the Schwarz lemma.